# I have a SQLAlchemy model with extra calculated fields introduced by a query. How do I serialize this with pydantic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have a table of *posts* and a table of *post_votes*. A post vote can have a value of +1 or -1. For example,

```
posts
   id title
1:  1   foo
2:  2   bar
3:  3   baz

post_votes
   id post_id value
1:  1       1     1
2:  2       1    -1
3:  3       1     1
4:  4       2     1
```

I've set up SQLAlchemy models for `Post` and `PostVote` as follows. (In reality, *post_votes* also includes a user_id, but I've excluded it here.)

**models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    votes = relationship("PostVotes", back_populates="post")
    
    
class PostVote(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post_votes'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('posts.id'), nullable=False)
    value = Column(Integer)
    post = relationship("Post", back_populates="votes")
```

I've also defined a pydantic model for serializing a Post instance to JSON.

**schemas.py**

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Post(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

This works great. I can fetch a post by id with something like `db_post = db.query(models.Post).where(models.Post.id == id).one()` and serialize it to JSON using the pydantic Post *schema*.

...but now I want to include the total number of likes (+1s) and dislikes (-1s) in the resulting JSON. I can update my pydantic schema simply by adding attributes

```
likes: int
dislikes: int
```

but I can't figure out how to write a SQLAlchemy query to "play nicely" with this schema. The closest thing I can come up with is

```
# sum the likes and dislikes by post_id
stmt = db.query(
  models.PostVote.post_id,
  func.count(1).filter(models.PostVote.value == 1).label('likes'),
  func.count(1).filter(models.PostVote.value == -1).label('dislikes')
).group_by(models.PostVote.post_id).subquery()


# left join to posts
db_post = db.query(models.Post, stmt.c.likes, stmt.c.dislikes). \
  join(stmt, models.Post.id == stmt.c.post_id, isouter=True)

# filter by post_id
db_post = db_post.where(models.Post.id == 1).one()
```

This returns a tuple like `(<db.models.Post object at 0x10577b850>, 2, 1)`. When using FastAPI, when I set my response_model as `schemas.Post`, this throws an error, presumably because pydantic is expecting *likes* and *dislikes* to be attributes of the Post model - not values in a tuple alongside it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by discovering and implementing [SQLAlchemy Hybrid Attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid).

In essence, I add an attribute called `likes` and another attribute called `dislikes` to my `Post` model without actually inserting these columns into the `posts` SQL table.

Here's what the addition of `likes` looks like.

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    votes = relationship("PostVotes", back_populates="post")

    @hybrid_property
    def likes(self):
        return sum(v.value == 1 for v in self.votes)

    @likes.expression
    def likes(cls):
        return select(func.count(1).filter(PostVote.value == 1)). \
            where(PostVote.problem_id == cls.id). \
            label('likes')
```

Now when I fetch a single `Post` instance

```
db_post = db.query(models.Post).where(models.Post.id == 1).one()
```

I get back a single Post instance with `likes` as an attribute

```
print(db_post.likes)  # 2
```

This then flows nicely into my pydantic model.

### Performance?

One thing I'm still unsure about is the strain this puts on performance. There are times when I want to fetch a post but don't need to know the associated likes / dislikes count. I'm not sure if this attribute loads lazily or how to force it to do so.